# Why can I not see "Add to Favorites" in the newest DataGrip?

Tags: datagrip

I can not see "Add to Favorites" in the newest DataGrip-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That was in [What's new](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/whatsnew/#miscellaneous)

New Bookmarks tool window
Before we had two very similar instances – Favorites and Bookmarks. As the difference between the two could sometimes be confusing, we’ve decided to stick to just one – Bookmarks. We’ve reworked the workflow for this functionality and made a new tool window for it.

From now on, all the objects or files you mark as important (with the F3 shortcut on macOS or F11 on Windows/Linux) will be located in the new Bookmarks tool window.

Comment: i know this,but i don't found add into Bookmarks  function

Comment: i found it s only allow add the consoles,don't allowed workes on the table again,it,s  work well on before version

Comment: I find this problematic as well, when we have hundreds of tables bookmarking them is useful. I confirm the feature is missing now.